# How to set the pre-selected item on AngularJS select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am struggling to get Angular's select ng-options to select the item that is already present when the form loads.

I have a model (ctrl.modelEl.make) that is a car make, with name and id. It's part of the broader model that the form is working on. It's pulled down from the database over a ReST API.

To populate the car make dropdown, I do a ReST call to the database and get a list of all the makes (ctrl.makeListEl).

Here is my select:

```
<select
ng-model="ctrl.modelEl.make.id"
ng-options="item.name for item in ctrl.makeListEl track by item.id"/>
```

I tried `ng-selected = "ctrl.modelEl.make.id"` but it made no difference.

In case there might be a race condition from the two separate database calls, I put the ctrl.makeListEl creation inside the success callback for the ctrl.modelEl creation but it made no difference.

From what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326164/setting-the-selected-item-in-angularjs-select-directive) using the id of the main model and tracking by id of the dropdown list model should enable Angular to pre-select the dropdown item with an id that matches the id of the main model.

But it's not working for me when the user edits an existing database entry. The select box is blank when it should have whatever was already in the database.

I am stuck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

John

Comment: `select` matches the object/value of the model with either the `track by` values or the `select as` values (see more in docs for [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)). Reproduce your issue in plunker, if you need more help

Comment: Give `$scope.item.name = 'the item'` a try..

Comment: I often see that suggestion, but I don't understand how to take advantage of it. item doesn't exist in the controller until after it's been added to the DOM by the select directive. So how do I set item.name in the controller? I'm using the 'controller as var' pattern, rather than injecting $scope into my controllers.

Comment: I figured it out! rather than matching by id as suggested elsewhere I had to match by a combination of model and model.id like this:
    `ng-model="ctrl.modelEl.make"
    ng-options="item.name for item in ctrl.makeListEl track by item.id"`